# Programmatic way to re-arrange functions in scripts in R

Tags: r, function, parsing, devtools

My team has dozens of functions living in several different R script files.

We have realized the we would like to move some of these functions from, say, R file A to R file B and other functions into a not-yet-existing R file C.

Is anybody aware of any tools or packages that can facilitate the parsing and rearranging?

I'm hoping not to re-invent the wheel.

Perhaps in devtools?

Comment: Have you thought about packaging them into a library for your team to use?

Comment: @SymbolixAU yes! That's one of the reasons we're hoping to get it all organized!

Comment: This question seems a bit too broad or opinion based to be a good fit here. Plus questions for tool recommendations are considered off topic. You really just need help cut-and-pasting functions? What's the technical challenge here and how exactly would a tool be helpful? What are the input and outputs you expect. A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) may make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose all my functions are in `file.r`,

```
a <- function(x) x+1
b <- function(x) x+2
```

I can load them in a fresh session,

```
source("file.r")
```

and output them in new files,

```
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(name) dump(name, file=paste0(name,".r")))
```

(here creating two files, `a.r` and `b.r`, but obviously you can arrange them differently.